# неправильный захват хоткея в PyCharm на debian KDE

Tags: debian, pycharm, jetbrains, kde

при зажатии shift и нажатие на мышь выделяется окно (становится прозрачным), а не ставит мульти курсор. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё. Сам Разобрался.

Вот решение:
https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/desktop/9893449

> Настройки системы -> Поведение окон -> Поведение окон -> Действия окна -> Доп. клавиша